# Add values to array in the same key

Tags: php, arrays

I've two arrays

```
118 => array:7 [
    "date" => "19.10.2016"
    "time1" => "dfg"
    "purpose1" => "dfg"
    "chair1" => "dfg"
    "time2" => "dfg"
    "purpose2" => "dfg5"
    "chair2" => "5345"
  ]
  123 => array:7 [
    "date" => "20.10.2016"
    "time1" => "gdf"
    "purpose1" => "gdfg"
    "chair1" => "gdf"
    "time2" => "gdfg"
    "purpose2" => "gdf"
    "chair2" => "534534"
  ]
  124 => array:7 [
    "date" => "20.10.2016"
    "time1" => "gdf"
    "purpose1" => "gdfg"
    "chair1" => "gdf"
    "time2" => "gdfg"
    "purpose2" => "gdf"
    "chair2" => "534534"
  ]
```

and

```
0 => {#231
    +"label_id": "D101102E"
    +"id": 118
  }
  1 => {#232
    +"label_id": "D1011100"
    +"id": 123
  }
  2 => {#233
    +"label_id": "D1011100"
    +"id": 124
  }
```

Where `id` is key in first array, and value in second array. I want add `label_id` to first array as value in the same `id` as key. I already try use array_fill_keys and array_push but it's not the point. Thank you

Comment: Show us your code ([mcve])

Comment: how did u try adding it?

Comment: You need to iterate over the second array and simply set the new values one by one.

Comment: The label_id should be in first array according the id in second and first array. I was tryied few methods,but i was wrong way. I dont exacly how done it

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through the first array, then in a nested loop, iterate through the second array comparing the outer key to the inner id. If you have a match, then append the value to the outer array and continue to the next item.

```
<?php

$a = [
    118 => [
        "date" => "19.10.2016",
        "time1" => "dfg",
        "purpose1" => "dfg",
        "chair1" => "dfg",
        "time2" => "dfg",
        "purpose2" => "dfg5",
        "chair2" => "5345",
    ],
    123 => [
        "date" => "20.10.2016",
        "time1" => "gdf",
        "purpose1" => "gdfg",
        "chair1" => "gdf",
        "time2" => "gdfg",
        "purpose2" => "gdf",
        "chair2" => "534534",
    ],
    124 => [
        "date" => "20.10.2016",
        "time1" => "gdf",
        "purpose1" => "gdfg",
        "chair1" => "gdf",
        "time2" => "gdfg",
        "purpose2" => "gdf",
        "chair2" => "534534",
    ],
];

$b = [
    0 => [
        "label_id" => "D101102E",
        "id" => 118,
    ],
    1 => [
        "label_id" => "D1011100",
        "id" => 123,
    ],
    2 => [
        "label_id" => "D1011100",
        "id" => 124,
    ],
];

foreach($a as $key => $value){
    foreach($b as $k => $v){
        if($key === $v['id']){
            $a[$key]['label_id'] = $k;
            continue;
        }
    }
}

print_r($a);
```

> ```
> Array
> (
>     [118] => Array
>         (
>             [date] => 19.10.2016
>             [time1] => dfg
>             [purpose1] => dfg
>             [chair1] => dfg
>             [time2] => dfg
>             [purpose2] => dfg5
>             [chair2] => 5345
>             [label_id] => 0
>         )
>
>     [123] => Array
>         (
>             [date] => 20.10.2016
>             [time1] => gdf
>             [purpose1] => gdfg
>             [chair1] => gdf
>             [time2] => gdfg
>             [purpose2] => gdf
>             [chair2] => 534534
>             [label_id] => 1
>         )
>
>     [124] => Array
>         (
>             [date] => 20.10.2016
>             [time1] => gdf
>             [purpose1] => gdfg
>             [chair1] => gdf
>             [time2] => gdfg
>             [purpose2] => gdf
>             [chair2] => 534534
>             [label_id] => 2
>         )
>
> )
> ```